# Draw/Design html without using <table><tr><td>

Tags: html, css, html-table

I would like to draw an table without using `<table><td><tr>`
I had googled any find many solution, so people said can use `<div>` + css
any easiest way or other best practice to draw it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`display` CSS attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Syntax) to achieve that :

```
div {
  display: table;
  display: table-cell;
  display: table-column;
  display: table-colgroup;
  display: table-header-group;
  display: table-row-group;
  display: table-footer-group;
  display: table-row;
  display: table-caption;
}
```

You obviously need to put your CSS in your stylesheets but [the idea is](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#display-table) :

```
<div style="display: table;">
  <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">
      Here is a cell.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you can use a markdown language such as jade or you can use a html tag such as a div and display it as a table using css.

Answer (score 0):

The `<table><tr><td>` are for implementing tables in the best way. why you dont use them?

you can implement the Table with This simple codes:

HTML

```css
.table{
 border:1px solid black;
 clear: both;
}
.table>div{
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 border:1px solid red;
}
.table>div>div{
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
 border: 2px solid yellowgreen;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.clearfix{
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>table</title>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="table">
 <div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
  <div>item</div>
 </div>
 <section class="clearfix"></section>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why?
The table element is precisely the element you want to use to draw tabular data.

There is, rightly, a trend in modern web design that frowns on using tables **for positioning**. This does not mean you should never use tables.

A bit of history. Before CSS was invented and properly supported by browsers, tables where heavily relied on to position content. Frankly they do a great job in this regard. It is very easy to create a table that position design elements precisely where you want them, **but** only assuming the users of your website have a monitor with similar aspect ratio and resolution to yours and that they look at your website full screen.  It is very hard to *flow* design elements with tables.

The very thing that makes them bad for positioning is what makes them perfect for tabular data (i.e. data that should be displayed in a table). Imagine if the cells in a financial report moved around and changed positions when it was resized.

To sumarize:

1. For tabular data use tables.
2. For positioning use CCS. You've already been given some examples for this, but frankly CSS positioning is too big and gnarly a problem to discuss in a single answer. Read some tutorials, try to use some CSS to place things and when you get stuck with anything more specific the stack**overflow** community will be here for you.